# Identify cat5 and cat5e wiring visually

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have some network cabling running in the house. I wanted to know if they are cat5 or Cat5e. Unfortunately I don't have access to the part of the wire where it's written. Mainly I want to run gigabit network, so want to know if they are cat5 or Cat5e. Adding a pic of the termination here. [image]

Also visually how do you tell them apart?

Comment: It's not enough that you have the right cable,  the specification also convers connectors and installation.  I can tell from the picture that the green wire probably won't meet CAT-5E specs regardless of the type of cable.

Answer (score 1):

Cat5 vs Cat5e is a specification of cable quality, not a different kind of cable or a different kind of jack. It should be written on the insulation periodically along it's length. I found a picture of an example: https://www.lanshack.com/Assets/Cat5e_stock.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that you cannot see the labeling on the jacket, and you almost certainly do not want to spend hundreds to thousands of dollars on specialized testing tools, the simplest thing to do is to try it and see. Get two computers, hook one at each end, see if they negotiate a gigabit connection between them. Then use iPerf (or similar tools) to send large amounts of data back and forth between the two computers. If the connection maintains gigabit speed (in practice, you probably won't see more than 800Mbps) without packet loss, then you should be fine. If there is packet loss, then you know that your cable, your patch panel, your jack, or your patch cables are not capable of gigabit.